# How is the desired status in the Debian Package Manager determined?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

For example, if I run the following command `dpkg -l ‘*compiz*’` the output is as follows:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
pi  compiz         1:0.9.12.2+1 all          OpenGL window and compositing man
ii  compiz-core    1:0.9.12.2+1 amd64        OpenGL window and compositing man
un  compiz-core-ab <none>       <none>       (no description available)
[more output deleted]
```

The output is a little cryptic. There are several detailed explanations on StackExchange, of which, [example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean?rq=1), is one. Likewise, `man dpkg` and `man dpkg-query` give similar explanations.

The first character in the first field, ‘p’, in our example output above, indicates the desired status of the package. Which is the status that the packaging system thinks the package should be in.

What is the underlying meaning of the desired status? I.e. Why does the packaging managing system have an idea of what status a package should be in? I could see that an intelligent system would recommend (or desire) a package to be purged if it was only ever used as a dependency to an already removed parent package. However, this is not the case in our example.

In our example, the package ‘compiz’ is installed, however `dpkg` believes it should be purged, or at least that it is desirable that the package is purged, why is this? Moreover, how does this particular field work in general? I.e. how does the system decide on a ‘desired status’ for a package and what are the underlying reasons for this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p` is NOT what the packaging system "thinks" the desired status should be.

It's what you, or someone else, has TOLD it that it should be - e.g. with a program like `aptitude` or `synaptic`, or even a simple utility like `apt-mark`.

It is marked to be purged the next time an `apt-get dselect-upgrade`, `apt-get dist-upgrade`, `aptitude full-upgrade` or similar is run.

apt is great at dependency resolution, but it's not "intelligent" and it doesn't make decisions like that for you.  It tries to do what you told it to, to the best of its ability.  Usually that Just Works.  Sometimes it either bails out because the conflicts are unable to be resolved automatically, and sometimes when you run it, it offers to remove hundreds of packages you don't want it to so you have to say "no".  In cases like that, you'll have to resolve the problem yourself (with the help of tools like `aptitude`).

If you want to change the desired status of the `compiz` package, you could run something like:

```
apt-mark install compiz
```

**Note**: as is always the case with packages, this will interact with the Dependencies and Conflicts of other packages.  If, for example, it gained that `p` status because you used `aptitude` to mark another package to be installed that happens to conflict with compiz, then that creates a dependency conflict that will have to be resolve when you run `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Technically speaking, it corresponds to the selection status of a package, and can be manipulated “en masse” using `dpkg --set-selections`; the changes can then be applied using `apt-get dselect-upgrade`.

Comment: yeah,  i didn't want to get bogged down in tech detail for this answer.  And i also didn't want to mention dselect-upgrade when dist-upgrade has the same effect (does `dselect-upgrade` even work if you don't have `dselect` installed and configured with an access method?)

Comment: I don’t think `dist-upgrade` has the same effect as `dselect-upgrade`... The former upgrades everything, removing packages if necessary, the latter applies selection changes only (it doesn’t upgrade additional packages, unless necessary as a side-effect of selection changes). `dselect-upgrade` works without `dselect`.

Comment: @cas thank you. I think I was thinking too deeply about it. Also, the text book I am learning from is misleading in its explanation. Thank you for your answer. It is really just a flag set by a user? In this particular instance, I'm unsure how it has been flagged as 'p'. I did run `sudo apt-get purge compiz`, but aborted the command when prompted; I wanted to compare the command-line solution with `sudo aptitude purge compiz`. Interestingly the results vary, package management appears to be somewhat of an art-form.

Comment: @case_2501 yes, it is just a flag set by the user. `apt-get` and `aptitude` use different dependency resolvers, so they handle package sets differently and can come up with different solutions.